# Rotate planets on several orbits at different speed

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, three.js

I'm writing a simple solar system using `Three.js`. At this time I have added 3 planets, every planet is rotating on its axis. At the middle I have added the sun.

- For every planet I create a different group (`mesh`);
- All the planets are in a main group (`Object3D`);

I can:

- rotate every planet on its axis (using planet object/group);
- rotate every planets on theirs orbits (using main object/group).

The problem is that when I make a rotation in the main group of for example `1`, every planet is  moving by 1. For example:

[image]

If I rotate a planet by 180 degrees, every planet is rotating by 180 degrees on theirs orbits. So how can I rotate every planet with a different speed?

I suppose that don't need the main group and I must write an algorithm and use it for every planet, but I don't know how algorithms like that works. Can somebody help me?

**Important parts of code:**

... main loop:

```
function loop() {
    jQuery.each(planets, function( key, value ) {
        value.rotation.y += 0.005;
        value.rotation.x += 0.005;
    });

    group.rotation.z -= 0.005;

    requestAnimationFrame( loop );
}
```

... adding a planet:

```
var data = {
    0: {
        texture:  "images/telos.png",
        radius:   10,
        segments: 20
    },
    1: {
        texture:  "images/ako.png",
        radius:   8,
        segments: 20
    },
    2: {
        texture:  "images/alba.png",
        radius:   21,
        segments: 20
    }
};
var planets = {}
jQuery.each(data, function( key, value ) {
    var planet = creator.planet({
        texture:  value.texture,
        radius:   value.radius,
        segments: value.segments
    });
    planet.position.set( key * 60, 0, 0 );
    planets[ key ] = planet;

    group.add( planets[ key ] );
});
```

Any tips?

Comment: can you console.log your `data` variable

Comment: It's just an object with planets informations. I have edited the main message.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
value.rotation.y += 0.005;
```

Is the key. Here is where you are rotating all of the planets by the same angle per 'tick'. Is you want different speeds, each planet needs to hold a different speed value, so first:

```
var planet = creator.planet({
    texture:  value.texture,
    radius:   value.radius,
    segments: value.segments,
    speed:    value.speed
});
```

Then you need to access that value:

```
value.rotation.y += value.speed;
```

Then make sure to send in a speed value when you create the planets.

If you want actually realistic values of speed, they can be calculated from the radius using [Kepler's laws of planetary motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion).  The ratio is inverse square, so you could do something like this:

```
var planet = creator.planet({
    texture:  value.texture,
    radius:   value.radius,
    segments: value.segments,
    speed:    1/(value.radius*value.radius) * 100 //change 100 to taste
});
```

Comment: I have already tried that. The problem is that it rotate planets on its own axis, and not on its own orbit.

Comment: @guest459473 - Did yo eve figure this out? I am starting to work on animations, and i too came across this issue. All items orbit same speed, but on a different  radius from central (sun).